# nodejs imap read only calendar events

Tags: node.js, events, calendar, imap

Am able to connect and pull emails from microsoft exchange server and gmail imap server using nodejs imap library.

But

1. how can i read/pull only calendar events (not required normal emails).
2. how can i read/parse the complete event data such as From address, To address (participants), event location, from datetime and end datetime etc., as microsoft exchange server calendar event is different than gmail calander event

Please share the sample script, if possible :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please post some working code or the apis / libraries you are using to get these emails?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/imap is the library which am using now to pull the emails